# ng-show not respecting boolean

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

So I am a relative newbie to angular attempting to make a nested comments solution where every level below the first has the reply area hidden until you click reply on the respective comment.

So I have my driective that renders all of the comments, nests them, etc, but the hiding of the nested reply fields isnt working. But it should be.

```
        p {{raShowReply}}
        .wrap(ng-show="raShowReply")
            p {{raShowReply}}
```

Thats my code. It outputs

```
false
false
```

on my page. why? its fales in the first p, apparently true when ng-show is evaluated, and false in the 2nd p. However since its the same variable and these are basic angular bindings, there should be no way for it to be different like that should there be?

Comment: can you post a plunker with representative code? tough to debug without seeing what's actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are sharing objects with directives, not primitives (such as a boolean).  Objects are passed by reference, booleans aren't.

```
 p {{myObj.raShowReply}}
    .wrap(ng-show="myObj.raShowReply")
        p {{myObj.raShowReply}}
```

Then, share the `myObj` object (which has a property raShowReply), and when one changes, the other will too.